# Kafka read the whole topic in cmd JAVA app

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to use Kafka stream with java application which runs in cronjob and read the whole topic each time. Unfortunately, for some reason, it commits the offset and on the next run, it reads of the last offset. I have tried various ways, but unfortunately without success. My settings are as follows:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app_id");
streamsConfiguration.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
streamsConfiguration.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
```

And I read the topic with the following code:

```
Consumed<String, String> with = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String());
with.withOffsetResetPolicy(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST);

final var stream = builder.stream("topic", with);


stream.foreach((key, value) -> {
                      log.info("Key= {}, value= {}", key, value);
});

final var kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), kafkaStreamProperties);
kafkaStreams.cleanUp();

kafkaStreams.start();
```

But still, it reads from the latest offset.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Streams commits offsets regularly, so after you run the application the first time and shut it down, the next time you start it up, Kafka Streams will pick up at the last committed offset.  That's the standard Kafka behavior.  The `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` only applies when a consumer doesn't find an offset, so it relies on that config on where to start.

So if you want to reset it to read from the beginning the next time on startup, you can either use the [application reset tool](https://kafka.apache.org/33/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html) or change the `application.id`.  If you get the properties for the Kafka Streams application externally, you could automate generating a unique name each time.

Comment: Changing the application.id is not ideal,because server will still keep this consumer info(from old instances) and I will run the java app often in scheduler. I will check the reset tool if can I use it via java code.

Comment: @user1089362 Just run the reset tool from the scheduler as well. Wrap both in a shell script

Comment: I don't have shell script, I have Java application which starts kubernetes.